# New Agent per build with Scripted Pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins

I built a scripted pipeline that requires docker to spin up to run the new code being deployed.

Since each docker instance runs on port 8081, only one build can run per agent.

Each build agent has 4 available executors, so I need to manually set the executors to 1 each time an agent spins up.

Is there any way I can still continue using a scripted pipeline and make sure that only one job is executed per agent?

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one job you could use the following property to get running only the latest build

```
disableConcurrentBuilds()
```

You could also use the lock/milestone steps to block a stage

https://jenkins.io/blog/2016/10/16/stage-lock-milestone/

Finally you could set the port dynamically to be something else than 8081

with a bash command and python:

```
PORT=$(python -c 'import socket; s=socket.socket(); s.bind(("", 0)); print(s.getsockname()[1]); s.close()')
```

then you whould pass the PORT variable to your docker command in order to map the internal port to the new external one we got from the variable